# Share data (and cached) from a single instance service between many components

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm creating a service that will pull data from server, then load that data into a property to be used later on, then notify all component that the service "is ready". The idea of loading data into a property is so that components can query it synchronously (through some methods) 
the problem that I'm having is that each component trigger a new http call.

So the question is how can I make only one http request and then notify all component when data is "ready"???

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TypelistService {
    private readonly baseURL = `${environment.myEndpoint}/api/typelist`;
    private list: Type[];
    private iSeeYou: Observable<ServiceStatus>;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        console.log('Hello Constructor'); // <-- this line execute only once as expected
        this.iSeeYou = new Observable((observer) => {
            observer.next({ status: 'calling' });
            this.http.get(this.baseURL).subscribe((data: Type[]) => {
                this.list = data;
                observer.next({ status: 'ready' });
                observer.complete();
            });
        });
    }

    init(): Observable<ServiceStatus> {
        return this.iSeeYou;
    }
    getAllTypes() {
        return this.list;
    }
    getItemById(id: number): Type {
        let item: TypeError;
        this.list.forEach((i) => {
            if (i.id === id) {
                item = i;
            }
        });
        return item;
    }
    getItemByName(name: string): Type {
        let item: TypeError;
        this.list.forEach((i) => {
            if (i.name === name) {
                item = i;
            }
        });
        return item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to let other components be aware of the data is available and ready. You can declare your `list` as a `BehaviourSubject` in the service. This way every time there is a change or update in the list every subscriber will get notified and receive the latest value available.

EX:

```
listData: BehaviorSubject<Type[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
```

and then return it as Observable once you receive the data:

```
iSeeYou() {
//make service call get the data and push to list
        this.listData.next(data);
    }
```

You can expose list as Observable to others, so that other components do not mess with Subject value:

```
list = this.listData.asObservable();
```

Now you can subscribe to the list in components and get the update as soon as the list changes. All the subscribers will have the latest value from list.

read more about [BehaviorSubjects here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject).